# Search Icons - lens - with the 3 states

Tags: android, android-icons, statelist

I need the icons of the standard Android search button - lens - with 3 states normal, focused, pressed. 
could any one provide me with this icons with 3 states?

regards,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be automatic in Android. follow the example. you can replace "state_orange" with any image files:

for your control:

```
android:background="@color/back_color_selector_blue_gradient"
```

back_color_selector_blue_gradient.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/state_orange" />
    <item android:state_selected="true" android:drawable="@drawable/state_orange" /> <!-- focused -->
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/background07" /> <!-- default -->
</selector>
```

background07.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">


    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <gradient android:startColor="@color/grayBlue3"
                android:endColor="@color/lightBlue" android:angle="270"
                android:centerColor="@color/lightBlue" />
            <!-- border width and color -->
            <stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="#FFDDDDDD" />
            <padding android:left="1dp" android:top="1dp" android:right="1dp"
                android:bottom="1dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>

</layer-list>
```

state_orange.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <solid android:color="@color/orange" />
</shape>
```

Comment: Many Thanks ...May I ask what is @color  .. it's not a standard resourse directory in Android project file .. right?!

Comment: But I'm getting this error:  Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'centerColor' with value '@color/lightBlue').
as shwon below:

Comment: change it to a color like #E9EDFB or define an xml file in "values" folder named "colors.xml" and put in it this: `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
 <color name="orange">#FFB84D</color>
 <color name="lightGreen">#C8FFD7</color>
 <color name="darkGreen">#22CB68</color>
 <color name="lightBlue">#EFF8FB</color>
</resources>
`

Comment: Many Thanks again ... I'm just missing the color value grayBlue3.. could you please provide it?

Comment: Put it in the colors.xml. It is very very easy.